# Which is faster to execute, if( c== 0 && d==0 && etc...), or if(c==0) if(d==0) etc...?

Tags: performance, if-statement

My question is:

if I have an if statement with lets say 10 conditions, if I put them all in one if statement will the compiler check the condition of all 10 statements? or it'll break as soon as it finds one false condition?

In If else the execution will end as soon as it finds a false condition, is it the case in e.g. `if(c==0 && d==4 || r ==3 && etc...)`.

Comment: `if (c==0 && d==0)` is NOT logically equivalent to `if (c==0) else if (d == 0)` anyway. They do not represent the same control flow.

Comment: I apologize, I meant if (c==0 && d==0) ,if (c==0) if (d == 0)

Answer (score 2):

This is called **short-circuiting**.

In C++, for example, for nested `&&` conditions, it is guaranteed that the check will stop at the first encountered `false`.

This is of course highly language-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the boolean operators && and || use short circuit or not.
In languages like C, C++, C#, Java, that is the case.

Short circuit means that going from left to right if the value of the whole boolean expression can be accurately deptermined the rest of the expressions are not evaluated.

Comment: So if the language has short circuit feature, which one will be faster, using the boolean operators or not to use them?

Comment: The compiler can compile them however it wants, including ignoring the shortcut behavior at the assembly level if it produces code that behaves _as if_ it was compiled exactly to the semantics. See [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/R4mBic) where the assembly evaluates _all_ the terms in the predicate, even though it could shortcut as soon as it sees a false value. The OP's question has no side effects, so such optimization is possible.

Answer (score 0):

it depends of the compiler... lazy and shortcuts

but most of them when you have (condition && condition..&&...) it will end at the first false...

so if(condition) is faster than 10 seperate if conditions....

Comment: That does not depend on the compiler, it depends on the language. E.g. in C, _all_ compiler have to shortcut the && and || operators

Comment: ok, it depends on the language standards..but I can still write my own compiler which will wait untill all conditions are read, and the case if(obj!=null && obj.toStr()) will throw an NullPointerException.... But yea I second your statement, you are right, it is the language specifications.

Answer (score 0):

For all reasonable languages/language implementations, these should be the same.

As others pointed out, the if (a && b && c) { code } syntax is optimised by reasonable compilers.

What hasn't been explained so far is that they're optimised partly because a compiler would have to be actively doing the wrong thing to make it less than optimised.  The reason is that this "short-circuiting" is usually built into machine code, too.  Your code will become assembly code something like:

```
IFNOT a, skip_code
IFNOT b, skip_code
IFNOT c, skip_code

code:
   ...

skip_code:
   ...
```

And so the CPU will step through each of these if checks until one fails.  If if finds one that fails, it just jumps to the end and ignores the rest of the if (...) { code } block.

Note how similar that looks to:

```
if (a) {
   if (b) {
       if (c) {
           code
       }
   }
}
```

They're the same thing.  Any sane compiler will make sure they're the same.

To do this WITHOUT short-circuiting, a compiler writer would have to actively choose something like:

```
SET badForCodeRun,False

IF a, skipA
SET badForCodeRun, True
GOTO skipCode

skipA:

IF b, skipB
SET badForCodeRun, True
...

skipCode:
```

Honestly, I can't even be bothered typing it the wrong way, because it's so long-winded and silly :)  Short answer is: it'll never be any other way than short-circuiting.